# Random Thread Number using OpenMP in Mac

Tags: c, macos, openmp

I have installed OpenMp using the following [link](https://shawnliu.me/post/configuring-openmp-and-mpi-on-mac/). When I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "omp.h"
int main(){
int ID;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    ID=omp_get_thread_num;
    printf("hello(%d)",ID);
    printf("world(%d)\n",ID);
 }
}
```

and run it, I get the following random response:

> `hello(35070288)hello(35070288)hello(35070288)hello(35070288)world(35070288)
> world(35070288)
> world(35070288)
> world(35070288)

As I understand, the output thread number should start and fork from 0.

Would appreciate your response! Thanks

Comment: 2 errors in your code: 1/ `ID` should be declared `private`, or even better, only declared within the `parallel` region and become private to the thread which created it; 2/ `omp_get_thread_num` is a function, not a variable, and should be called using parentheses as `omp_get_thread_num()`

Comment: **Read your compiler warnings** - and enable them.

Comment: Ahh yeah...that was stupid of me. Thank you. :)